# pagebreaks with wrapfig

Tags: page-breaking

I am writing a document for a game, where there are several character descriptions available, including portrait pictures. I'm trying to typeset this, but I have some problems with preventing pagebreaks happening at odd places. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setlength\parskip{3pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\person[6][black]{
  \vspace{1em plus 5cm}
  \FloatBarrier
  \filbreak
  \begin{samepage}
  \noindent\begingroup\small\textbf{\large #2}\\#3 (#4) -- #5\endgroup\par
  \noindent\textit{#6}\par
  \end{samepage}
  \nopagebreak
  \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{3cm}
    \begingroup
    \color{#1}\rule{3cm}{3cm}
    \endgroup
  \end{wrapfigure}%
  \nopagebreak
  \@afterindentfalse%
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\person[red]{Name}{Occupation}{Employed by}{Role}{Short description}

\lipsum[1]

\person[green]{Name}{Occupation}{Employed by}{Role}{Short description}

\lipsum[1]

\person[blue]{Name}{Occupation}{Employed by}{Role}{Short description}

\lipsum[1]

\person[yellow]{Name}{Occupation}{Employed by}{Role}{Short description}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have (more or less blindly) added things like `\filbreak`, `samepage`, `\nopagebreak` and `\@afterheading` to suppress page breaks at points where I don't like them and encourage them at places where I do like them. However, the result still contains a very odd page break: [image: odd page break]

I would like to instruct LaTeX to prevent pagebreaks between the "header" and the "body" of a character description at any cost, even if that means leaving a quarter of a page empty at the bottom or adding excessive stretch between the sections.

I do however want to allow LaTeX to break within the text of a paragraph as long as it doesn't conflict with the position of the `wrapfig`, as some are long enough to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to make `person`  a `\section`? The `titlesec` package has a `nobottomtitles` option, and defines a `\bottomtitlespace` length (minimum vertical space which must remain at the bottom of the page to place a section title at the bottom).

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to have the additional text segments added directly below the actual name, which requires me to mess around with the command definition anyhow. Or are you just suggesting to make the first line a `\section`? Would a `\subsection` work as well?

Comment: I think so. `Short description` might be an unnumbered subsection. You can see details in the package documentation, §3.3, *Spacing related tools*.

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of making the name a `\subsection`, as the document already contains some `\section`s. Would it be required to have every single piece of text be some sort of structural command? That might be a bit clumsy...

Comment: Of course, the section level to be used is up to you. Maybe there are simpler solutions. You can't use `decription` lists/sublists, as `wrapfigure` doesn't work well  with lists. For the rest, you didn't describe precisely the structure of what you try to achieve, so I can give only general suggestions.

Comment: The `\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}` did the trick, although it needed some massaging with `\pagebreak[3]` before the `\subsection` to avoid LaTeX producing lots of clubs and widows...

Comment: Fine! May I suggest (maybe you know it) there exists a small `nowidow` package which simplifies setting this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind for the future!

Comment: You could probably achieve the same effect with \needspace (needspace package).